# How to read a string from an RCData resource in NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have an ANSI string in an RCData resource and I'd like to store that string in a variable. I've got to the point where I can get the pointer to the resource and the size of the data:

```
; HMODULE GetModuleHandle(LPCSTR lpModuleName);
System::Call "kernel32::GetModuleHandle(i 0) i.r0"

; HRSRC FindResource(HMODULE hModule, LPCSTR lpName, LPCSTR lpType);
System::Call "kernel32::FindResource(i 0, t 'DATA', i 10) i.r1"

; HGLOBAL LoadResource(HMODULE hModule, HRSRC hResInfo);
System::Call "kernel32::LoadResource(i r0, p r1) i.r2"

; LPVOID LockResource(HGLOBAL hResData);
System::Call "kernel32::LockResource(i r2) p.r3"

; DWORD SizeofResource(HMODULE hModule, HRSRC hResInfo);
System::Call "kernel32::SizeofResource(i r0, i r1) i.r4"
```

Now I'm not very sure what to do. I'm quite new to NSIS and I think my problem is that I don't really understand how variables work in NSIS and what happens (what value it has) when a variable is used as output of a System call with different types. What (I think) I need is to copy `$4` bytes from an address stored in `$3` to a new buffer and (probably?) terminate it with zero. I thought something like this could work:

```
System::Alloc ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}
Pop $5
System::Copy /$4 $5 $3
```

But it doesn't. After some experiments, I got to the point when this is working:

```
System::Call "*$3(&m$4.r5)"
```

But I really don't have a good idea why this is working, if it is the right way how this task should be handled and why the Copy version above didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the System::Copy code, $5 contains the memory address of the allocated buffer (as a string, as if someone did `sprintf(reg5, "%i", address)`). If you do `MessageBox mb_ok $5` you will just see this address. However, if you do `System::Call user32::MessageBoxA(p0,pr5,p0,i0)` you should see your string.

The System::Call code converts the source and/or destination using the type you specify. This is a perfectly valid way to do it and is less work than the copy code.

This is perhaps easier to visualize if we had something that needed type conversion instead of basically a byte copy in your specific case.

Imagine if in C we had

```
typedef struct { int foo, bar; } MyS;
MyS*ptr = allocandfill();
```

and in NSIS $1 is the value of ptr:

```
System::Call '*$1(i.r2,i1234)'
```

we often refer to this as System struct syntax and the * can be thought of as de-referencing the memory starting at $1 and interpreting the memory as a struct based on the types we specify.

In my specific example here, we are saying the first member is an int and I don't want to change the value/source (the dot) but I want the current value as output stored in r2 ($2). This will basically perform a `itoa` where $2 is the destination. The second member is another int and I'm overwriting its current value with the number 1234. In C this would be performing `ptr->bar = atoi("1234")`.

The third way to complete your task is to call a Windows function and get it to do the work:

```
System::Call `kernel32::lstrcpyA(m.r5,pr3)' ; or lstrcpynA if the string is not zero-terminated or you want to chop it to n characters
```

Comment: That's awesome, a lot of things make much more sense now, thank you so much! :) Maybe one more question - does `&m$4.r5` add the terminating '\0' to `$5`? The string in `$3` is not null-terminated. Since variables only contains strings and also the resulting string in `$5` seems to be displayed correctly, I suppose it does, I'd just like to make sure that the zero is not there by accident. Btw. would it be reasonable to think of variables as of `char[NSIS_MAX_STRLEN]`?

Comment: After some experimenting it looks like the result in `$5` really is null terminated, which is great. :)